# Magento 2. SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '100019997-1' for key 'SALES_ORDER_INCREMENT_ID_STORE_ID

Tags: magento2, sales-order, migration

After running the migration I find myself unable to place orders.

After some digging the error that is thrown is the one in the title:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '100019997-1' for key 'SALES_ORDER_INCREMENT_ID_STORE_ID
```

On `sales_order` there is `increment_id` value. My highest value is 100032938 but when the orderRepository saves the new order somehow 100019997 is generated. Now I have an order that already has that value and the `increment_id` column is an index which means unique values.

Deleting the existing order is not an option nor is truncating the `sales_order` table.

My question is how does Magento come up with this value 100019997.
I know that the first digit is he store id and I found information that the other number `199997` is taken from `sequence_order_1` table and the zeros are added by some formula. In the `sequence_order_1` I have  a value that is in the thirty thousands.

I've also tried. Cache cleaning and reindexing.

How can I make Magento or the DB (depending of who is responsible) to generate a valid increment_id when placing orders?

Any tips or pointers are appreciated. Thanks

PS: I've tried this with no success

1. Open MySQL database of your Magento 2 store with the help of phpMyAdmin.
2. Find the 'sequence_order_1' table . Note, that this table is located in the database itself, not in the 'information_schema'.
3. Hit the 'Operations' tab and edit the necessary 'increment_id' number under it.

Comment: Did you manage to get a fix for this?

Comment: I was migrating a db from M1 to M2. High volume of customers on M1. Deleted customers using direct sql. Existing quotes corresponding to that customers were not deleted. So I had a corrupt database. When placing a new order an existing quote was loaded. Magento took that pair of values from that existing quote. This was causing my problem. Fixed it bringing back the M1 database to a consistent state. Did the migration again. Everything worked fine. Not all the information I provided is 100% accurate as some time passed. You can debug the new order process and diagnose your problem.